# ANOVA using wide data table format

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2, anova, tidyr

My original data are in wide format as displayed in **Table A**.

Let's say I want to research whether veterans who have experienced different tours of military service suffer from different levels of depression.

I decide to run a one-way ANOVA test on the data with ***Depression_Score*** as the criterion and '***tour of duty served***' as the factor. I know I can reshape the data into long format as in **Table B**, and then run the ANOVA.

Here's my question though: is it possible to run an ANOVA test directly on **Table A** without reshaping the data into **Table B**?

If yes, then what R commands would I use to program this?

Table A:

```
ArmyVet_ID  Served_WW2  Served_KoreanWar    Served_VietnamWar   Depression_Score
110001          1              0                    0                3
110002          1              0                    0                1
110004          0              1                    0                4
110005          0              1                    0                3
110009          0              0                    1                7
110010          0              0                    1                5
```

Table B:

```
ArmyVet_ID    Served            Depression_Score
110001          WW2                    3
110002          WW2                    1
110004          KoreanWar              4
110005          KoreanWar              3
110009          VietnamWar             7
110010          VietnamWar             5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you drop one of the columns and feed it to `as.matrix`, you can get the same result as passing the combined factor:

```
anova(lm(Depression_Score ~ as.matrix(A[3:4]), data=A))
#Analysis of Variance Table
#
#Response: Depression_Score
#                  Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
#as.matrix(A[3:4])  2 16.333  8.1667  5.4444 0.1004
#Residuals          3  4.500  1.5000
```

Compared to the factor result as per table `B` in your example:

```
anova(lm(Depression_Score ~ I(factor(c(1,1,2,2,3,3))), data=A))
#Analysis of Variance Table
#
#Response: Depression_Score
#                               Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
#I(factor(c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)))  2 16.333  8.1667  5.4444 0.1004
#Residuals                       3  4.500  1.5000
```

Comment: Should it be `data=B` in the second case? One other clarification. If there were 4 columns of factors (instead of 3 as in this case), would I feed 3 of those columns `as.matrix`, and so on?

Comment: @user1883050 - it doesn't make any difference - `Depression_Score` is the same in both `A` and `B` in your examples. Yep, I believe you need to use `n-1` columns always, as you can only make `n-1` comparisons without doubling up. See the `Df` column and note that it is always `2` in the anova results.